# Traverse & Convert HTML based documentation directory to either TEXT or PDF

Tags: pdf, html, documentation

Documentation for a standard system package is contained in:

```
 /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-5.8.10 (distros: RHEL 6/Centos 6)
```

however it is all *.html.  I'd like to traverse all the files in the proper order and either generate a SINGLE PDF file or a SINGLE TXT file so the documentation can be printed and read off-line without going manually page-to-page.

How do I do this?

Comment: How do you define "in the proper order"?

Comment: @Scott -- like page 1 of the document would appear as page one in the output.  The files have names denoting function, not as their appropriate page number.  I invite you to take a look at the directory.

Comment: Sure, I’ll take a look — what are the IP address of your system, and a username and password that I can use? Since I can’t see your files, I don’t know what “files have names denoting function, not as their appropriate page number” means.  I would expect the first page of a file to be printed first, but I don’t know what you mean by “the document”.  So, as far as I’m concerned, you haven’t answered my question.

Comment: Note, the latest rsyslog doc is available as a pdf [here](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/rsyslog/latest/rsyslog.pdf), and for each feature says from which release it is available. Also, you might read the rsyslog chapter in the redhat sys admin guide [pdf rhel 7](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/pdf/System_Administrators_Guide/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-7-System_Administrators_Guide-en-US.pdf) (I couldn't find rhel 6).

Answer (score 1):

```
(find /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-5.8.10/ -type f -name \*.html -exec w3m -dump {} \; ) > /path/to/mydocs.txt
```

If the order in which `find` lists the files is to your organizational liking, you can use this to use `w3m` (a console HTTP client) to render the HTML for you, and roll them all up into one file.

If you don't like the order, you can eschew the `-exec` parameter to get the list of files, and then re-order them before chewing on that generated-and-sorted list with `w3m`.

Comment: (1) Oh, come on now! You know the rules about posting commands without explanations. (2) Why do you put the `find` command in parentheses?

Comment: (1) was an oversight as I got called away before I could edit in the anti-TLDR.

(2) my first draft was an iterated loop in a subshell; the `(stuff; things) > file` means you only have to deal with one redirect, and that repeated executions will give a fresh output file.

Comment: Hmmm....this is far from ensuring proper document ordering automatically ....which is what I wanted to get away from having to do examine all the files and do this manually.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

As I haven't found `w3m` from the previous answer on my system I would install `html2text` and run:

```
find /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-5.8.10/ -type f -name \*.html -exec html2text {} >> all_docs.txt \;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get them in the right order, you're going to have to check the table of contents and from that generate a list of the files, in order of the various sections/chapters.  Once you have that list, $HTMLLIST, you can use [wkhtml](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) to generate a pdf:

```
wkhtmltopdf --enable-local-file-access index.html "$HTMLLIST" rsyslog.doc.pdf
```

Make sure you use one of the releases [posted here](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html), as the ones in the repos can generally only handle a single html.